# How to display the latest line based on the file's name or the line's position in bash

Tags: bash

I have a tricky question about how to keep the latest log data as my server reposted it two times

This is the result after I grep from my folder :(i have tons of data, just to keep it simpler)

```
...
20150630-201427.csv:20150630,CFIIASU,233,96.21786,0.44644,
20150630-201427.csv:20150630,CFIIASU_AU,65,90.71109,0.28569
20150630-201427.csv:20150630,CFIIASU_CN,68,102.19569,0.10692
20150630-201427.csv:20150630,CFIIASU_ID,37,98.02484,0.27775
20150630-201427.csv:20150630,CFIIASU_KR,39,98.42257,0.83055
20150630-201427.csv:20150630,CFIIASU_TH,24,99.94482,0.20743
20150701-151654.csv:20150630,CFIIASU,233,96.21450,0.44294
20150701-151654.csv:20150630,CFIIASU_AU,65,90.71109,0.28569
20150701-151654.csv:20150630,CFIIASU_CN,68,102.16538,0.07723
20150701-151654.csv:20150630,CFIIASU_ID,37,98.02484,0.27775
20150701-151654.csv:20150630,CFIIASU_KR,39,98.42257,0.83055
20150701-151654.csv:20150630,CFIIASU_TH,24,99.94482,0.20743
...
```

The data actually came from many csv files, I only pick two csv files to make the example, and here are some explainations of this:

1. the example came from two files  `20150630-201427.csv` and `20150701-151654.csv`, and it has 4 columns which  correspond to date, datanme, data_column1, data_column2, data_column3.
2. these line have the same data date `20150630` and the same dataname `CFIIASU`,`CFIIASU_AU`...etc, but the numbers in the fourth and fifth column (which are data_column2 and data_column3) are different.

How could i keep the data of `20150701-151654.csv` based on the file's name and data date and apply it on my whole data set?

To make it more clearly. I'd like to keep the lines of "the latest csv" and since the latest csv is corresponding to the file's name, which in this example is 2015070. but when it comes to my whole data set i need to handle with so many 20xxxxxx.csv that i can't check it one by one.

for the example, i made this should end up like this:

```
20150701-151654.csv:20150630,CFIIASU,233,96.21450,0.44294
20150701-151654.csv:20150630,CFIIASU_AU,65,90.71109,0.28569
20150701-151654.csv:20150630,CFIIASU_CN,68,102.16538,0.07723
20150701-151654.csv:20150630,CFIIASU_ID,37,98.02484,0.27775
20150701-151654.csv:20150630,CFIIASU_KR,39,98.42257,0.83055
20150701-151654.csv:20150630,CFIIASU_TH,24,99.94482,0.20743
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The [XY](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) problem is asking about your attempted solution rather than your actual problem.

Comment: This smells like an XY problem indeed. All you need might be `files=(*.csv); grep 'regex' "${files[-1]}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question isn't clear but it sounds like this might be what you're trying to do (print all lines from the last csv mentioned in the input file):

```
$ tac file | awk -F':' 'NR>1 && $1!=prev{exit} {print; prev=$1}' | tac
20150701-151654.csv:20150630,CFIIASU,233,96.21450,0.44294
20150701-151654.csv:20150630,CFIIASU_AU,65,90.71109,0.28569
20150701-151654.csv:20150630,CFIIASU_CN,68,102.16538,0.07723
20150701-151654.csv:20150630,CFIIASU_ID,37,98.02484,0.27775
20150701-151654.csv:20150630,CFIIASU_KR,39,98.42257,0.83055
20150701-151654.csv:20150630,CFIIASU_TH,24,99.94482,0.20743
```

or maybe this (print the last line seen for every `20150630,CFIIASU` etc. pair in the input file):

```
$ tac file | awk -F'[:,]' '!seen[$2,$3]++' | tac
20150701-151654.csv:20150630,CFIIASU,233,96.21450,0.44294
20150701-151654.csv:20150630,CFIIASU_AU,65,90.71109,0.28569
20150701-151654.csv:20150630,CFIIASU_CN,68,102.16538,0.07723
20150701-151654.csv:20150630,CFIIASU_ID,37,98.02484,0.27775
20150701-151654.csv:20150630,CFIIASU_KR,39,98.42257,0.83055
20150701-151654.csv:20150630,CFIIASU_TH,24,99.94482,0.20743
```

Comment: Thank you i tried the second way you did, and it works. But i don't really understand the commands you wrote. could you kindly explain more clearly about the commands?

Comment: You're welcome. `!seen[$2,$3]++` is the idiomatic awk way to print the line associated with the 2 fields the first time they're seen. `seen[]` is just a user-defined name of an array, you could call it anything. The first time `!seen[$1,$2]++ is tested for any $2,$3 combination it has vaue zero so the negation  (`!`) of that is `1` and so the current line is printed. But then `seen[$2,$3]` is post-incremented (`++`) so the second and subsequent times a $2,$3 pair with those same values occurs, the test is negative and the line is not printed.

Comment: I think the rest is pretty clear from the awk and tac man pages but let me know if you have any specific questions after looking at those.